# Access backend APIs in Angular/React/Vue(front-end) and DJango/Node/Java/ASP.NET(back-end)

Tags: django, ide, frontend, backend, web-development-server

I have searched a lot but could not find any satisfying answer.
I want to know if any IDE provides an environment for web development using Angular and Django. And how to access Django APIs in angular.

please tell me.
I will be thankful for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes in mind is Visual Studio Code. It is very versatile and easy to set up for starting web development.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial

You have a lot of extensions which can make your life easier in developing by just typing in the search Angular. You'll finde code highlighter, debugger for chrome etc...
same goes to Django, fast easy set up, good extensions and you are ready to go.

Comment: I'm already using VS code for angular development. can I work on both domains(Angular+DJango) in the active project in VS code?

Answer (score 0):

I was not familiar with web development at that time. My question was about accessing APIs in frontend. All IDEs and Editors can be used for frontend and backend development.

**The main point to keep in mind is that your frontend will have its own server and backend will have its own server that will compile and react to changes you made in your code.**

Let's say your frontend server serves on **localhost** with **port:8888** and your backend server serves your APIs on **localhost** with port **8000**

By running both server at the same time you can access APIs in your frontend with backend routes like:

**'localhost:8000/login'**

**localhost:8000/user/user_id**